# Transofrming a list separated with spaces - putting each item on a new line and prepending it with a hyphen

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I have a list of string records separated by spaces

```sh
words="foo bar baz"
```

and I want to pretty print them, each on a new line, prepended with a hyphen:

```sh
- foo
- bar
- baz
```

How can I achieve that?

I found many ways of replacing the spaces with newlines, for example

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< $words
```

but I didn't have any luck applying them together with the hyphen and space... for some reason the following two lines return the same result:

```sh
tr ' ' '\n' <<< $words
tr ' ' '\n- ' <<< $words
```

I'm also having trouble prepending the first item with `"- "` without breaking the newlines in my console output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sed` seems nice:

```
sed 's/ /\n- /g; s/^/- /' <<<"$words"
```

or:

```
tr ' ' '\n' <<< $words | sed 's/^/- /'
```

If `$words` are simple words separated by spaces with no fancy characters like `*` `?` `[` similar, you could

```
printf -- "- %s\n" $words
```

Note that unquoted variable expansions undergo word splitting *and* filename expansion.

Comment: Works great, thank you! Do you know why does `tr ' ' '\n- ' <<< $words` and `tr ' ' '\n' <<< $words` return the same output?

Comment: `tr` like maps characters 1:1 from a list. So for example `tr abc def` changes `a` to `d`, `b` to `e` and `c` to `f`. Calling `tr ' ' '\n-'` translates space to `\n` and basically `-` and space do not map to any input, so they are just ignored. `tr` is like `y` command in `sed`.

Answer (score 2):

Could do

```
words="foo bar baz";b=( $words );for i in ${!b[@]}; do echo "- ${b[$i]}";done
```

Comment: Well, if it's an array, then just `printf "- %s\n" "${b[@]}"`

Comment: @KamilCuk Sure. Not using printf enough to be my first reflex. Nice alternative.

Comment: Well, then if using word splitting, then it's just `printf "- %s\n" $words`

Answer (score 1):

With `awk`:

```
awk 'BEGIN {RS=" "} {print "- " $0}' <<< "${words}"
```

Answer (score 0):

A series of sed commands does it:

```
sed 's/.*="//; s/"$//; s/ /\n/g;' <test | sed 's/^/- /'
```

Edit: Oops, I thought that `words="foo baz bar"` were the contents of a file...
@KamilCuk has a much cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

A version for `zsh`, building on some of the other answers and comments:

```
printf -- '- %s\n' ${=words}
```

In `zsh`, this can handle special characters, such as wildcards:

```
% words="foo? 'b'ar *bar b[a-z]"
% printf -- '- %s\n' "${=words}"
- foo?
- 'b'ar
- *bar
- b[a-z]
```